# Micro USB MHL To HDMI Adapter HDTV - not working on my Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, mhl, lg-g3

I have bought a `Micro USB MHL To HDMI Adapter HDTV Cable For Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300 Note2 N7100` from eBay, and just assumed backward compability (yes I know...)

So know I have this thing, and a Galaxy S5, and it's not working. On my sisters   LG G3 it's also not working.

Anything I can do beside giving it away to the next person who has a S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you're stuck.  I own the same cable for my S3, and, in researching it, I found that you must buy the exact cable for the specific phone you're using it with.  Samsung changed the pin configuration for the S3 ([see here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s-iii-accessories/214553-micro-usb-hdmi-adapter-s3.html)), so, you've got an incompatibility issue.